# terraform won't let me using colons and dashes in app settings for azure app services or functions

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to script out the terraform for an app service and azure function.  Both have app_settings and when we originally created them we used colons ':' and dashes '-' in our setting names.  The old version of Terraform was ok with this (0.14.2), but the newest version of Terraform (0.14.9) and Azurerm (3.0.0) don't like it.

Here's what the app service looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "hermes_core_api" {
  name = var.functions_app_r2_name[terraform.workspace]
  location = azurerm_resource_group.ermes_core_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ermes_core_resource_group.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.example_priorityfunc_service_plan.id

  site_config {
      ftps_state = "AllAllowed" 
  }   

  app_settings = {
      "Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey" = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.New_Relic_Key.value
      "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"          = "0"
      #other settings snipped
  }
  #connection strings and other stuff snipped too
}
```

When I do a terraform plan everything looks good.  When I do the apply it barfs with this error:

```
│ Error: creating Windows Web App: (Site Name "func-usw1-hermes-r2-core-dev" / Resource Group "RGP-USW1-HERMES-CORE-DEV"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="AppSetting with name 'Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey' is not allowed." Details=[{"Message":"AppSetting with name 'Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey' is not allowed."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"04072","Message":"AppSetting with name 'Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey' is not allowed.","MessageTemplate":"AppSetting with name '{0}' is not allowed.","Parameters":["Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey"]}}]
│
│   with azurerm_windows_web_app.hermes_core_api,
│   on hermes_core_api.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "hermes_core_api":
│    4: resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "hermes_core_api" {
```

Settings within our own application are not a big deal.  We can just rename them to get around this.  But stuff like Serilog seems more problematic.
What am I doing wrong?
Can I encode the characters or something to get around this?

Comment: Could it be that "Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:licenseKey" is specified more than once in the app settings {} block? (The code block in the original post shows `#other settings snipped`.)

Comment: Is this also disallowed by the API validation, and not just provider validation?

Comment: I would deploy it to test using a simple key name like "test" and if it succeeds then it would most likely be an api limitation. If the same error popped up I'd know my code is reading the wrong file or there's two app_settings blocks defined by mistake

Comment: I snipped settings for security/IP issues. As you can imagine this is my employers stuff so I don't want to reveal too much.  no of the app settings are duplicated.  And to really set folks to pulling hair out: the older versions of our terraform were able to do this stuff.  We have dahses and colons all through the settings and terraform was able to build the environment w/o issue